# C++, how to call functions when reading their ID number from a Mysql table?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a Mysql table that I am using as a list of different calculations that needs to be done.
Each line in the table has a column of type INT  that has the number of the function that needs to be called.
e.g. line 6, data, (function) 1.

I read all the lines one by one and I need to call the relevant functions for each line.

What is the best way to construct it in C++?

should I have another function that returns the pointer of the functions that needs to be called ?

Are there other recommended solutions?
Thanks

Comment: Do all these functions have the same signature?

Comment: I am still developing the algorithm, but I think that the answer is yes, the function gets the data from the line and continues from there, maybe later I will need to use functions with different signature. thanks

Comment: If you manage to have the same id everywhere, you can simply create a function pointer registry, as you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of the function (input/outputs) but assuming they are all the same, you can make an array of function pointers. For example:

```
std::vector<void(*)(int)> MyArray;
```

Will declare an array of function pointers returning void and taking one int as parameter. Then you can put the functions you want in it and when you want to call them you can use `MyArray[i]`

If the actual type for the function pointer is long and hard to type, you can use `decltype(MyFunction)` instead. This requires C++11 though.

Comment: thanks, it answers my question, just to understand.. what happens if I need to call functions with different signatures?

Comment: You can't put them in the same container. You can use trickery though. For example the SDL uses `void*` as parameter for the functions pointers you can pass to other functions. You can put a wrapper over it so it works (points on a different struct containing the arguments you want).

Answer (score 0):

Using function pointers may work may work but I would rather make use of something like Strategy pattern.

```
class DataProcessor {
public: 
    virtual void process(Data& data) = 0;
    // some other things like dtors etc
}
```

For each type of "function" you can create its corresponding DataProcessor.

To ease lookup, you may make use of a factory, or simply a `std::map<int, DataProcessor>` (instead of using int as key, will you consider using an enum?), or even a `vector`/array of `DataProcessor`.

Comment: Isn't that a bit overkill? It takes time to make a class for each function and your code gets really big.

Comment: 1. Better maintainability, 2. creating such class cost not much time more than using function pointer, for experienced developers at least. 3. "really big"? I doubt how much bigger the code will be compared with the function pointer approach.  Such kind of argument looks just like "why use vector? It is overkill. Using array is going to be faster and makes your code smaller".  I am not against using function pointer here actually, if OP knows he really needs compact code and will never needs the flexibility by using a class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please help me understand better the solution, assuming I have 2 types of functions: type 1: functions 1-5. type 2 functions 6-10. how many instantiations do you make of the DataProcessor? can you please show a small example,

Comment: It will be better if you can tell a bit more on what type 1 and type 2 differs, and what function 1-5 differs.  Normally, it will be 10 strategies I am going to instantiate.  However, I may only need to create 2 concrete strategy classes (Type 1 & 2).  It all depends on your requirement though.

Comment: I am just asking to understand the solution, not a complete example. assuming type 1 returns INT and type 2 returns String and there are 5 functions from each type, thanks

Comment: That's what I am trying to say: the way to solve can be very different.  It is hard to answer without proper context.  For example, if logic in 1-5 is basically the same, just differ by some parameters, then I can create only a `Type1DataProcessor` and instantiate 5 times using different param.  However if the logic are very different, then I would rather have 5 classes instead.  One thing to be sure is, no matter you are using Strategy pattern or simply function pointer, you would want to generalize as much as possible to make better encapsulation.  Having different signature is probably

Comment: one thing you want to generalize.   How your calling logic going to distinguish what to expect from the function?

Comment: so just to understand, if I instantiate 5 times, I still need to keep the pointers to the instantiated classes somewhere? or am I missing something? so the advantage is that I can keep more relevant data to the functions there?

Comment: yup, I think mostly correct.  Of course there are more advantages.  Have a look in the design pattern book, on related patterns (strategy, state, etc)

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, this is another way:

```
//Create only a function and make a switch statement in it:
void myfunction (std::pair<int,int> aRow) {  // function:
    int result;
    int data = aRow.second;
    int function_id = aRow.second;

    switch(function_id){
        case 1:{
            //Funcion with any signature
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            //Funcion with another signature
            break;
        }
        //and so on...
    }

    //do something with the result...
}

int main () {
//Fetch your mysql data here:
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > myMySQLdata;

    for_each (myMySQLdata.begin(), myMySQLdata.end(), myfunction);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am trying to build a library that will grow over time, each function also has stages to mimic a state machine, so I assume it will be hard to debug this way, thanks for the effort for writting it.

Comment: why would it be hard to debug? It's the simplest way to implement it (no function pointers). The main issue would be that you have to rewrite this function every time you want to add a new function to the list.